# Rider can't resolve symbol for UnityTest although the tests run (OSX, M1)

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit, rider

I recently started having this issue where although my tests run properly, Rider forgets the reference to the `[UnityTest]` attribute. It shows up as an error in Rider, but not in Unity. Although the namespace is already imported, after I do a quick action to fix the reference the errors disappear but only until the next save.

Mac OS: Ventura 13.0.1
Rider version: 2022.2.4
Unity version: 2021.3.15f1

I've attached a gif to show what exactly is happening:

[image: After saving rider loses the reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer in [this post](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008047460--Cannot-Resolve-Symbol-Rider-Windows-Unity-Resolve-symbols-between-Assemblies). I'm not sure what exactly went wrong and got cached but the solution was to **invalidate the cache** by calling this action:

**File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart**

Hope this will help others!

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with [Assembly definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)?

In that case you will need to add it there as dependency.

I suspect Rider's quick action basically does this within the `csproj` files but with the next save Unity recompiles and overwrites the `.csproj` files according to the assembly definitions

-> should be looking like e.g.

[image]

Comment: Yes of course, otherwise the tests wouldn't run :) But it's checked for all platform and I see that Editor is excluded for you. If I also exclude it then Rider doesn't show any errors anymore, but then I can't run the tests from Unity

Comment: @Narc0t1CYM it is not excluded .. they are all excluded except the editor ;)

Comment: You're right, my bad. Still, unfortunately the result is the same :\